# Mysteriously given 3:4 length?

Tags: geometry, triangles

can you find x here?
I think it is crucial to have all lengths which can be paired to 3:4. But I don't know how to use it.

[image]

Comment: Doubt. If $ HG,CB$ are produced upwards making triangle side lengths in proportion $ 3t, 5t$ then are   not lines $(GB,EF,HC)$ parallel due to similarity in triangles between parallel lines?$\dfrac{3t}{9}=\dfrac{5t}{15}.$ How is x=20 degrees instead of 0 degrees?

Comment: FYI: With a bit of Mathematica-assisted coordinate bashing, consistent with a GeoGebra sketch, I find the result to be $40^\circ$. This may help someone find a *good* approach to the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful for drawing two lines starting from G and H which are parallel to EF

Comment: Incidentally, there's nothing special about $20^\circ$ or the ratio $3:4$ here. (Barring degeneracies ...) So long as $$\frac{BF}{FC}=\frac{GE}{EH}=\frac{BG}{CH}$$ we always have $x=2\angle D$.

Comment: @blue hmm? It's really amazing. Is it another result of GeoGebra sketch?

Comment: @Detectives: Yeah. Having a GeoGebra sketch to play with made the generality clear. I was expecting some kind of ["adventitious angles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles) craziness, but the problem turns out to be pretty straightforward. See [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4592575/409).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of focus, and a change of orientation, really helps here. Specifically, focus on $\square HCBG$, and orient the figure so that $\overline{EF}$ is horizontal.

[image]

Suppose
$$\frac{GE}{EH}=\frac{BF}{FC}=\frac{GB}{HC}$$
where the common ratio ($\lambda$ in the figure) need not be $3/4$. Then the right triangles with hypotenuses $\overline{GB}$ and $\overline{HC}$ and legs parallel and perpendicular to $\overline{EF}$ are similar. Consequently, the extended hypotenuses make the same angle (say, $\theta$, which need not be $20^\circ$) with $\overline{EF}$, so that the angle they make with each other is $2\theta$. $\square$

Thus, for the problem at hand, $x=40^\circ$.

Comment: Very nice! You've beat me to it, though my answer would probably be much longer

Comment: Amazing solution~ Thanks!